# Quirk with geom_bar and ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I came across what I think is a quirk with the `ggplotly` function in R's `plotly` package.

When trying to wrap a `ggplot` plot (with `geom_bar` and `stat = identity`) inside the `ggplotly` function, negative values were coerced into positive values.

The following is a toy example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

set.seed(12345)

x <- data.frame(
    x = 1:10,
    obs = floor(rnorm(10) * 100)
)

# x  obs
# 1   58
# 2   70
# 3  -11
# 4  -46
# 5   60
# 6 -182
# 7   63
# 8  -28
# 9  -29
# 10  -92

test_plot <- ggplot(x, aes(factor(x), obs)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
test_plot
```

[image]

```
ggplotly(test_plot)
```

[image]

The values do not seem to be coerced when using other `geoms`. Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/560

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(12345)

df <- data.frame(
  x = as.factor(1:10),
  obs = floor(rnorm(10) * 100)
)
plot_ly(x = df$x, y = df$obs, type = 'bar', name = 'Plotly') %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = 'x'), yaxis = list(title = 'obs'), barmode = 'group')
```

[image]